# WordSmith or Antcoc?

Tags: software, corpus-linguistics

**[Corpus linguistics] [Software recommendation]** Hi guys, I have a small corpus I wish to analyze using a frequency list I have in order to extract vocabulary. What I want to do is:

1. Compare the words in my corpus against a frequency list I have, and
   see what percentage of lexical coverage each band offers.
2. See which words appear in my corpus divided by frequency band, but
   with info about how frequent they are in my corpus.
3. See the distribution of certain words in different files in my
   corpus.
4. Check which words collocate with some words of my interest.

My questions are:

- I know RANGE does number 1 and 2, but do you know if it's possible to
  use my own frequency list to check against?
- I know WordSmith and AntConc do 3 and 4, but which one would you
  recommend using?
- I've heard you have to clean your corpus before using it but I've
  been seeing videos and I don't see they delete proper names,
  punctuation marks, nor contractions.
- One more, my corpus are the scripts of a TV show called Gossip girl
  which I found online and then corrected watching the series, is it
  legal to use it?

Details: my frequency list is taken from a corpus of English learners

I'm new to corpus linguistics and I would appreciate if you could give me some pointers as to where to find those answers. Please help me, I'm losing my mind. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sed, Awk, Excell. learn [RegEx](https://xkcd.com/208/)